# c# wpf change font color with color picker

Tags: c#, color-picker, xceed

I want to change the text color of a label shown in a WPF Application within a setting menu.

so so far Just have the WPF label with the name lbText and the standard Foreground="white".

Now I added a Menu with a Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorPicker Control.

But I cant figure out how to change the color now with this Control? I always get the Error that Brush != Color, but I just want to change the Foreground value of my Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foreground` is actually of brush, not limited to a solid color. If you want just one plain color as foreground, construct a `SolidColorBrush` with the chosen color.

```cs
// suppose your color picker is named yourColorPicker
var color = yourColorPicker.SelectedColor;
if (color.HasValue) // any color selected
    lbText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color.Value);
else // no color selected
    lbText.ClearValue(Control.ForegroundProperty);
```

Check out more brushes for WPF at https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview

Comment: Oh, right. That Xceed picker selected color is nullable.